# Seeking information on "Knesseth Israel" charity

Tags: tzedakah-charity

A relative recently passed away and I was distributing the proceeds of Pushkas found in the relatives house. One of the [Pushkas](http://picclick.ca/Judaica-Jewish-Charity-Box-For-Jerusalem-Rabbi-Meir-232131316854.html#&gid=1&pid=3) was for the "Central Committee Knesseth Israel Charity of Rabbi Maier Baal Haness" with an address on it of 214 E Broadway, NYC. I mailed them a check, which was returned "Attempted - Not Known - unable to forward". I called a number I found online and it is disconnected. Does anyone know if this charity merged or if it moved where its new address is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They moved to Lakewood, NJ after the 9/11 attacks as they were unable to access their building for over a year. The current address is 136 Powderhorn Drive, Lakewood, NJ 08701.